# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting an error when trying to run an example on spark. Can anybody please let me know  what changes do i need to do to my pom.xml to run programs with spark.

Comment: what is the example you point to ? Add an example and show the error

Answer (score 6):

Currently Spark only works with Scala 2.9.3. It does not work with later versions of Scala. I saw the error you describe when I tried to run the `SparkPi` example with `SCALA_HOME` pointing to a 2.10.2 installation. When I pointed `SCALA_HOME` at a 2.9.3 installation instead, things worked for me. Details [here](http://cornercases.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/getting-the-spark-demo-to-work/).

Answer (score 3):

You should add dependecy for scala-reflect to your maven build:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue using the Scala-Redis 2.9 client (incompatible with Scala 2.10) and including a dependency to scala-reflect does not help. Indeed, scala-reflect is packaged as its own jar but does not include the Class missing which is deprecated since Scala 2.10.0 (see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/o81XWrq-E5o)).

The correct answer is to point to an installation of Scala which includes this class (In my case using the Scala-Redis client, the answer of McNeill helped. I pointed to Scala 2.9.3 using SBT and everything worked as expected)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error is raised in Kafka's api. I change the dependency from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

fixed the problem.